# How do I get a function to modify any of the parameters?

Tags: c, fractions, function-call

**My objective:**

I have to create a function which adds up two fractions.

I've defined a new `struct` (typedef) called `fraction`.

The function can't have a return type `fraction`, it has to be `void`, therefore it has to modify one of the parameters entered, how can I achieve this? Pointers maybe? How would you modify my code to achieve it?

**This is my code:**

```
typedef struct{
    char sign;
    int num;
    int den;
} fraction;

void sum(fraction, fraction, fraction);

int main(void) {

    fraction op1, op2, solution;

    sum(op1, op2, solution);

    return 0;
}

void sum(fraction f1, fraction f2, fraction sol){

    if (f1.sign == '-') {
        f1.num = f1.num * -1;
    }

    if (f2.sign == '-') {
        f2.num = f2.num * -1;
    }

    sol.num = f1.num*f1.den + f2.num*f1.den;
    sol.den = f1.den * f2.den;
    sol.sign = '+';

    if (sol.num < 0) {
        sol.sign = '-';
        sol.num = sol.num * -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: So, you mean, you want to print the result in the caller?

Comment: The third arg needs to be a pointer, with consequential changes in the call and in the assignments to the solution.

Comment: the C language is quite capable of applying math operations in variables, including `float` and `double` variables.  So why make it complicated?

Comment: a major thing to note: those instances of the struct `function` in `main()` are never initialized.  Passing them to a sub function is undefined behavior., because they are not initialized, so will contain what ever trash happens to be on the stack where they are located.  As an example of the problem.  the field `f1.sign` has a one in 256 chance of being '-'`

Comment: regarding: `sol.num = f1.num*f1.den + f2.num*f1.den;`  this calculation can overflow, resulting in undefined behavior.   Having undefined behavior in a program is never acceptable

Answer (score 4):

This is generally a bit broad, but to show you the *pointers*, let me add, yes, you're on correct path.

> *Pointers maybe?*

Yes. To elaborate on the **why** part :

C uses pass-by-value for function argument passing, so, you cannot modify an argument from inside a called function and expect that value to be *retained / reflected* in the caller. However, if we pass a pointer as an argument, the pointer itself cannot be modified from the called function as stated above, but any change made to the memory location pointed to the pointer, will be *reflected* in the caller (as long as the pointer is valid, per se).

Now, coming to the **how** part:

You need to pass the third argument (or, whichever that is supposed to store the result) as a pointer to the structure variable. This way, modifications to the memory location pointed to by the address, inside the called function will be reflected in the caller.

So, your function signature will look like

```
 void sum(fraction f1, fraction f2, fraction * sol)
```

and the function call will look like

```
 sum(op1, op2, &solution);
```

Now, the access to `sol` inside the called function, I leave to you.

Comment: So, I must declare the function this way: void sum(fraction f1, fraction f2, fraction *sol) and call it this way: sum(op1, op2, &solution); is that all?

Comment: @Adria don'f forget, type of `sol` is changed, so you gotta take care of that, too.